# Charles Maynes plug-in matrix scheme in Nuendo

Tags: nuendo, plug-ins

Hi!

There is a great post on Designing Sound in which Charles Maynes talks about a cool way to work with plug-in effects: http://designingsound.org/2013/01/a-plug-in-vector-matrix/

I wonder is it possible to implement such a scheme in Nuendo?

I can't find the way to create a multichannel bus ("group track" in Nuendo) with individual mono channels. There is a possibility to create child busses for a multichannel bus, but I couldn't find how to send fx-signals to those separate busses.

I will be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done... you need to use the multichannel child busses...in output (press F3)

and in the mixer view (F4) assign the inputs and outputs for channels.. like in protools..
Let me do it and send a pic

Answer (score 1):

Nuendo has Group Channel Track.

- Just create wanted mono busses and mix it down to Main Output or Create 5.1 (up to 10.2) Bus (STEM) STEM. Use **@aural-chef** method with F4 shortcut.
- In mixer there is Direct routing which help you to route faster...
- For details take a look into manual there is a lot of information there!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll get around more easily if you do this in something like Bidule or Usine. These patcher type of programs were pretty much made for this kind of stuff in the first place, but I believe there aren't many if any of these types of programs in PT's plug-in formats and thus may drive Pro Tools users to figure out this kind of "workarounds".